# How to copy a pattern from a string variable in perl

Tags: perl

I need to copy the content of a sentence between `=` and `)` using perl.
say for example:

```
 $temp="06/18/2012 08:35:35(PID=2150)";
```

now I need to copy the value `2150`, between `=` and `)` to a variable `$temp2`.

Answer (score 7):

That's easily achieved using a regex:

```
my ($temp2) = $temp =~ /=(\d+)\)/;
```

Just look for a sequence of digits between `=` and `\)`. The closing parenthesis has to be escaped since parentheses are used for capturing groups.

The reason you have to enclose `$temp2` in parentheses is because you need to force list context to return the results of the match. In scalar context you would just get the number of matches; 1 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using just index() and substr() (as an excercise, if anything ;).

```
$temp="06/18/2012 08:35:35(PID=2150)";
$temp = substr $temp, index($temp, "=") + 1, (index($temp, ")") - 1) - index($temp, "=");
print $temp;
```

Comment: +1 for taking care to show how it can be done without regexes - useful for discussion why we need regexes after all. )

Comment: haha, for sure - shows that while people (at first, at least) say regex is gross-looking... the alternative can be much grosser!

Comment: Another novelty solution is `my $temp2 = join "", grep /\d/, grep {/=/../\)/} split //, $temp;`. Not very robust though.